# Back Button intercepted for ever - Phonegap/Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

In my Android phonegap/Cordova 3.5 project, I have 3 html pages (a button in **index.html**  calls **page2.html** where there is another button calling **page3.html**).

In **page2.html** I override backbutton doing this in **deviceReady**:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

then

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
            console.log("onBackKeyDown");
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
```

but in **page3.html** I want to let Android controlling backbutton so I do not override it in page3.html.
Instead in page3.html backbutton is disabled.

Questions:

1. Is this the expected behaviour (overriding one means overriding for
   ever)?
2. How to get rid with this? (leave the control of backbutton to
   Android anytime I want to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the real solution to this question is probably to remove the event with this API:

```
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

I found it [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.it/2011/05/overriding-back-button-in-phonegap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the page in the OnBackKeyDown event:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
  var pagename = // get the page name here
  if ( pagename == page3.html ) {
    history.back();
  }
  else {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  }
}
```

Comment: this function is to be included in every html and where I do not want to intercept the backbutton event, right?

Comment: No, change your existing  function . Check your page in this function where you want to go back you call history.back() else your exit function call

Comment: it's working only if the function is included everywhere, in the page where it is not included the backbutton page is just disabled.

Comment: you can create a javascript file and place this function in  it and add reference to all your html file

Answer (score 0):

You can back button behaviour according to each page. Example is shown below.

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
        if ($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "home"
            || $.mobile.activePage[0].id == "login") {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }else if($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "inspection"){
            e.preventDefault();
            back();
            //return false;
        }else if($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "noDetails"){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.mobile.changePage("home.html");
            return false;
        }else{
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }

    }
```

I am using jQuery Mobile- gives more control over page transitions.

Comment: this way, you include this function in every single file, right?

Comment: If you are using jqueryMobile, you just have to place this only once.(in the first page.) because jQM uses ajax to populate each pages. but if you don't, yes you have to use it everywhere.